# Mixing native executables and llvm bitcode libraries

Tags: fortran, llvm, jit

**Situation**

I have a program (written in fortran) which consists of:

1. A set of core routines, used every time the program is run.
2. A large collection of alternate routines, only one of which is used for each run, selected by the user at the start.

The user may reasonably select different alternatives for subsequent runs.

Most of the building time is spent compiling the alternatives, which is frustrating when I know only one will be used each time. Most of the run time is spent in the alternative routine, which is short but called many times.

**Idea**

Compile all the core routines to a native executable and all the alternatives to an llvm bitcode library. At runtime, the selected alternative only is automatically compiled and linked. This would hopefully save a lot of building time and slow down the running only marginally.

**Questions**

1. Is this even possible and if so, how?
2. Is it a good idea? Are there better ways of achieving a similar result?

Comment: If you know what alternatives you will be using on compile time, then it's better to modify your build system so you can select which alternatives should be compiled. But if you make the decision at runtime, then i don't see why build times are problem for you.

Comment: Is the user selecting the alternate procedure at run time or compile time?  If it is run time then there should be no problem with build time since you are only doing it once and there is no additional overhead per run.  If they have to recompile to choose the alternate procedure then that isn't a run-time choice, it is a compile-time choice.  Can you clarify exactly how the user chooses the alternate?

Comment: The user writes a file specifying the configuration for each run. The choice of alternate is in there. Build times are annoying for debugging and testing.

Comment: If you can find a llvm compiler... I heard that someone started creating flang, but that was really just in the beginning phase.

Comment: Then the solution is to modify your build system so it'd compile only requested alternative.